# Unity3D: Random Values Appear Identical?

Tags: random, unity-game-engine, direction

In my breakout clone I'm trying to split the ball, at which point they assume random directions to move in. This direction is decided in the Start() of each ball instance. Upon observation is seems that the more balls I split, the more obvious it becomes that all balls move in the same direction, towards the upper-right corner of the screen. Can anyone help? Why are the values the same every time the balls split? This is my code:

```
 // Use this for initialization
     void Start () 
     {
         ballRB = transform.rigidbody;
         direction = new Vector3(0,1,0);

         //If there's only one ball in the field, being this current one, the default up motion should be used.
         if (GameObject.Find("StartBall").GetComponent<StartBall>().numBalls <= 1) ballRB.AddForce(direction*1000f, ForceMode.Force);
         //If not, there are more balls, which means the player split the ball. A random direction should be used in this case.
         else ballRB.AddForce(GenerateRandomDirection(), ForceMode.Force);

     }


     Vector2 GenerateRandomDirection()
     {
         int randX = Random.Range(0,360);
         int randY = Random.Range(0,360);
         randDirection = new Vector2(randX, randY);
         return randDirection;
     }
```

Comment: Well, maybe you put a `Debug.log(randDirection);` before `return randDirection;` to check if they are similar. In a quick test just generating some Vector2 basically like you did, they where not.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, I accidentally put in degrees (0 to 360) so results were always positive.
Problem solved.